# Count number of occurrences of token in a file

Tags: bash, shell, grep

I have a server access log, with timestamps of each http request, I'd like to obtain a count of the number of requests at each second. Using `sed`, and `cut -c`, so far I've managed to cut the file down to just the timestamps, such as:

> 22-Sep-2008 20:00:21 +0000
>   22-Sep-2008 20:00:22 +0000
>   22-Sep-2008 20:00:22 +0000
>   22-Sep-2008 20:00:22 +0000
>   22-Sep-2008 20:00:24 +0000
>   22-Sep-2008 20:00:24 +0000

What I'd love to get is the number of times each unique timestamp appears in the file. For example, with the above example, I'd like to get output that looks like:

> 22-Sep-2008 20:00:21 +0000: 1
>   22-Sep-2008 20:00:22 +0000: 3
>   22-Sep-2008 20:00:24 +0000: 2

I've used `sort -u` to filter the list of timestamps down to a list of unique tokens, hoping that I could use grep like

```
grep -c -f <file containing patterns> <file>
```

but this just produces a single line of a grand total of matching lines.

I know this can be done in a single line, stringing a few utilities together ... but I can't think of which. Anyone know?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I think you're looking for

```
uniq --count
```

> -c, --count
>           prefix lines by the number of occurrences

Comment: Note that with other data sets you may need to sort(1) before uniq(1), as uniq will only group adjacent duplicates.

Comment: Yes, but the OP's already said he's sorted things so I assumed he was on top of that sort of thing ...

Comment: I had to use `uniq -c` on OS X, `--count` gave me an error.

Answer (score 1):

Using AWK with associative arrays might be another solution to something like this.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case you want the output in the format you originally specified (with the number of occurences at the end):

```
uniq -c logfile | sed 's/\([0-9]+\)\(.*\)/\2: \1/'
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [awk](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html):

```
cat file.txt | awk '{count[$1 " " $2]++;} \
                    END {for(w in count){print w ": " count[w]};}'
```

Answer (score 0):

Tom's solution:

```
awk '{count[$1 " " $2]++;} END {for(w in count){print w ": " count[w]};}' file.txt
```

works more generally.

My file was not sorted :

```
name1 
name2 
name3 
name2 
name2 
name3 
name1
```

Therefore the occurrences weren't following each other, and `uniq` does not work as it gives :

```
1 name1 
1 name2 
1 name3 
2 name2 
1 name3 
1 name1
```

With the awk script however:

```
name1:2 
name2:3 
name3:2
```

Answer (score -3):

maybe use xargs?  Can't put it all together in my head on the spot here, but use xargs on your sort -u so that for each unique second you can grep the original file and do a wc -l to get the number.